# What command lists all files beginning with "a" and having 1 or 2 digits that follow?

Tags: linux, filenames

What command lists all files beginning with "a" and having 1 or 2 digits that follow?  (The output might display a0, a1, a2, a3, a00, a01, a99,... but not a333, not b12, not art53,...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell,

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
printf '%s\n' a[[:digit:]](#c1,2)(.)
```

The pattern `a[[:digit:]](#c1,2)(.)` would match any regular file whose name starts with an `a` followed by one or two digits.  The `(.)` at the end makes sure we only get names of regular files, while `[[:digit:]](#c1,2)` matches one or two digits.

In `sh` or `bash` etc.,

```
printf '%s\n' a[[:digit:]] a[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]
```

This would list all names that start with an `a` and then has either one or two digits ofter that (we use one pattern for names with one digit, and another for names with two digits).  It is not certain that you'd only get names of regular files though (you may also get names of directories etc.), and if one or the other pattern (or both) does not match *any* name, the pattern will remain unexpanded (use `shopt -s nullglob` in `bash` to make the non-matching patterns be removed instead).

To weed out any non-regular file, use a loop:

```
for name in a[[:digit:]] a[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$name"
    fi
done
```

Here, we apply an explicit `-f` test to each name.  This test will be *true* if the name refers to a regular file (or to a symbolic link to a regular file).  If the test is *true*, we print the name.

Comment: I am using linux and the command you said didn't seem to work, I am not sure where did i make mistake.

Comment: @AhsanQureshi I show three commands. The first one is for the `zsh` shell, and the other two are for `sh` and `bash` and similar shells. The last two commands are doing slightly different things, depending on how you want to interpret the word "file", and they will also behave differently if the patterns _do not_ match. I have described this in the text.

Comment: [aqureshi@cmsy255 labs]$ a[[:digit:]](#c1,2)(.)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: is there any easier method to do it ? e.x is there any ls command that can do this ?

Comment: @AhsanQureshi Since you are using `bash` (not `zsh`), the first command would not work for you. You never said what shell you were using, so I did not know what kind of solution you needed. You should try the other two commands (you should also read the text in my answer). The `ls` command is not needed to list the names of the files.

Comment: second command worked perfect, you are awesome.

Comment: @AhsanQureshi Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: will accept it right now.

Comment: You are mixing of several concepts: first Linux is a kernel, not a full OS. This is not your fault (as there is an effort by some to make people think that Linux is the whole thing). Then there is `ls` it never does pattern matching, **never**. So when you do `ls *.png` and get a list of files ending in `.png` it is not `ls` that is doing this. It is your shell, it passes the derived list to `ls`. Try it with echo. **e.g.** `echo *.png`

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution, and one not dependent on which shell you're using, might be something like

```
Helios:t larry$ ls -1
a0
a10
a100
ax
axe
b4
Helios:t larry$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype egrep -regex '\./a[[:digit:]]{,2}'
./a10
./a0
```

But that spawns an additional process.